# One method having two queries with insert and update with @Transactional Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a method with `@Transactional` annotation used, where we are inserting a record, and at the same time we are updating the same record for one column it's not getting updated. When we checked the DB only the insert query got executed.
Sample code:

```java
@Transactional
public void testMethod(){

insert(Entity class); // inserting data in DB with id, processed, createdate column

update // updating processed column data for the above inserted record based on id

}
```

No error is thrown from the above method, but when I checked the DB only the insert query worked successfully but the update query didn't work.

Can you please suggest how to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Why an update insetad of modifying the entity? Also the update probably fails because there is nothing yet in the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please suggest instead of update what is the better approach? i want to insert the data first because based on the id i have to do the validation, if the validation passed then I have to update the value otherwise no update

Comment: Set the value on the object, instead of issuing a query. The state will be synchronized automatically.

Comment: Thanks alot @M.Deinum it worked

Comment: @M.Deinum care to make that a proper answer? So it can be upvoted and accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating with a query won't work as there is nothing to update in the database just yet. As you are using JPA just update the entity after your validation instead of issuing a query.